# Implementing Pagination in Database connector

Tags: mule

Is there anyway to set pagination using configurations in select statement of in-built database connector of AnyPoint studio in mule?
I have tried reading the doc and I could not find any configurations to achieve pagination. If not should I write my own custom connector to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement this yourself.
Best way is to take in the query params you use for pagination, store them as variables and use those flowVariables in your select statement.

Depending on the DB you are connecting to you can then use mechanism such as LIMIT and OFFSET for MySQL as explained [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp)

Another option would be to filter a specific range in DataWeave, but in terms of performance that is unnecessary data fetching, that may not be the nicest option because you still fetch all the data and filter it to a range later.